# Best way to manage asynchronous / push communication with web clients on a Spring based Java server

Tags: java, spring, backbone.js, websocket, socket.io

I need to push events to web clients in a cross-browser manner (iPhone, iPad, Android, IE/FF/Chrome/etc.) from a Spring based Java server. I am using backbone.js on the client side.

To my best knowledge, I can either go with a Web socket only approach, or I can use something like socket.io.

What is the best practice for this issue, and which platform/frameworks should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're interested in an AJAX Push engine.  [ICEPush](http://www.icepush.org/) (same group that makes ICEFaces) provides these capabilities, and works with a variety of server- and client-side frameworks.  There is also [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Lightstreamer](http://www.lightstreamer.com/).

My company is currently using it to push real time financial data from a web server.

Comment: What's the advantages of using a commercial solution for this? Is there a specific reason that you are using this framework?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/) or [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) may fit your needs. Don't have a real experience in that scope, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [socket.io](http://socket.io) as you mentioned in your question, if you're doing browser based eventing from a remote host. Socket.io handles all the connection keep-alives and reconnections directly from javascript and has facilities for channeling messages to specific sessions (users). The real advantage comes from the two-way communication of WebSockets without all the boilerplate code of maintaining the connection.

You will need to do some digging for a java implementation thoughConsider running the server directly from [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/).